# How to create an "array" of multiple tkinter Scale widgets with Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tkinter-scale

I am trying to create a GUI using Python 3.2.3 and the `tkinter` module. I need an "array" of `Scale` widgets but cannot for the life of me figure out how to return the values except by creating the `Scale` widgets one at a time and having a separate function for each one called by its `command` keyword argument passing the `var`.

I can loop the widget creation bit and increment the row and column parameters as necessary but can't figure out how to retrieve the values of the `Scale` widgets.

In "Basic" each widget would have an index which could be used to address it but I cannot find how anything similar is implemented in Python. Even worse - just with a single `Scale` widget, I used:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

w = Scale(master, from_=0, to=100)
w.pack()

w = Scale(master, from_=0, to=200, orient=HORIZONTAL)
w.pack()

mainloop()


#To query the widget, call the get method:

w = Scale(master, from_=0, to=100)
w.pack()

print w.get()
```

And got the response:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
> ```

I am assuming this is some kind of version issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using Python 3? Your example is Python 2.
This simple example works with 1 widget:

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
w = Scale(master, from_=0, to=100,command=lambda event: print(w.get())) 
w.pack()
mainloop()
```

With an array of widgets, you put them in a list

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
scales=list()
Nscales=10
for i in range(Nscales):
    w=Scale(master, from_=0, to=100) # creates widget
    w.pack(side=RIGHT) # packs widget
    scales.append(w) # stores widget in scales list
def read_scales():
    for i in range(Nscales):
        print("Scale %d has value %d" %(i,scales[i].get()))
b=Button(master,text="Read",command=read_scales) # button to read values
b.pack(side=RIGHT)
mainloop()
```

I hope that's what you want.

JPG

Comment: Thank you very much - that is precisely what I wanted. One supplementary question is could you recommend a book or other reference/tutorial source ? I have been plagued by information relating to the wrong version of Python or Tkinter or tkinter.

Comment: I began with [http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_labels.php](http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_labels.php) but it's very simple. I don't know any comprehensive book or tutorial. Perhaps someone else can give a better tip.

Comment: Thanks again, you have been very helpful. That site looks good to me - "simple" is what I need at the moment.